# whitespace-pre-line is not working on TailwindCSs

Tags: tailwind-css

I am making a blog, and I want the space on the code I write display as it is. Now, when I add the whitespace-pre-line, it does not work????

```
 <p className='whitespace-pre-line'>
            The Box is a passion project of mine that showcases the journals I authored. Its objective is to keep me active at all times and to constantly practice my design and web development abilities as I learn. I understand that the design and user experience are not optimal but I promise that it will improve with time. 








            Although the content may not be relevant to you, I promised that you would acquire some insight from my perspective. We all have distinct journeys and paths to take, but we are united because we all want to succeed.
          </p>
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkyKh.png)

I am expecting it to be like this.

[expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3hzV.png)

Comment: Please provide a Tailwind-CSS-Play example. It looks like your code is running fine so it might be possible some other elements cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use pre tag instead of paragraph tag

Here is how you can do that:

```html
<pre>
The Box is a passion project of mine that showcases the journals I authored. Its objective is to keep me active at all times and to constantly practice my design and web development abilities as I learn. I understand that the design and user experience are not optimal but I promise that it will improve with time. 








Although the content may not be relevant to you, I promised that you would acquire some insight from my perspective. We all have distinct journeys and paths to take, but we are united because we all want to succeed.
</pre>
```

Comment: it doesn't work,